# What RSpec tests should I write for this stand a lone Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have a small ruby app with one model, the model uses ActiveRecord & the find_by_sql method as the query is a little complex, it loops over the results and produces a CSV file, this file is then uploaded to a remote FTP server.

Just wondering what are the RSpec tests that I should consider writing for this non-rails app?

First time writing non-rails tests and have been hit with "testers block" :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of things I would likely test for.

1. Test that the application can connect to the FTP server and upload a trivial file.
2. Test the query with various points of data.
3. Test the CSV generation with irregular data (a forgotten field and other PEBCAK errors)
4. Test that the CSV file contains **all** data.
5. Test that the application responds gracefully (or as intended) in the event of a failure.

Posting any code or the query itself would allow us to offer much better advice.

Comment: Would you run this test only when the program is modified or before each time its executed? (Great points btw)

Comment: When the program is modified or FTP server information is changed.